# How to convert a String to Hex array

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, string, array, hex

I am trying use a HMI display. If I want to send a data, for example I want to write "TOPWAY" to 0x00000080 address it should like that:

```
    Serial.write(0xaa); // packet head
    Serial.write(0x42); // VP_N16 string write command
    Serial.write(0x00); // VP_N16 address
    Serial.write(0x00);
    Serial.write(0x00);    
    Serial.write(0x80); 
    Serial.write(0x54); //T
    Serial.write(0x4f); //O
    Serial.write(0x50); //P
    Serial.write(0x57); //W
    Serial.write(0x41); //A
    Serial.write(0x59); //Y
    Serial.write(0x00); //string end with "\0" 
    Serial.write(0xcc); // packet tail
    Serial.write(0x33); // packet tail
    Serial.write(0xc3); // packet tail
    Serial.write(0x3c); // packet tail
```

I want to make a method like SendString(String abc) to send that like above. I need convert string a hex array and call in Serial.write(array[i]). Can you hep me?

Comment: There is no such thing as a hex array. Everything is all just numbers. Even letters are numbers. Your string is already an array.

Comment: `Serial.print("TOPWAY");` should do it

Comment: @Juraj you mean like that for total query like above: Serial.write(0xaa);  
    Serial.write(0x42);  
    Serial.write(0x00);     Serial.write(0x00);
    Serial.write(0x00);    
    Serial.write(0x80); Serial.print("TOPWAY"); Serial.write(0x00); //string end with "\0" 
    Serial.write(0xcc); 
    Serial.write(0x33); 
    Serial.write(0xc3); 
    Serial.write(0x3c); . if Not? please show me as answer not in comment.

Comment: the answer is below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know anything about the particular display, but based on the information provided I hope this is at least shows the foundation of one way you could approach a final solution.

**Update:**

- Incorporated great improvements and a fix from Edgar in the comments.
- String overload.
- Display baud rate suggested by mehmet

```cpp
#define DISPLAY_DEVICE Serial
#define DISPLAY_DEVICE_BAUD 9600

static uint8_t displayPktStart[] = {
    0xaa, // packet headchar
    0x42, // VP_N16 string write command
    0x00, // VP_N16 address
    0x00, // ...Fill
    0x00,
    0x80
  };

static uint8_t displayPktEnd[] = {
    0x00, // End of text
    0xcc, // packet tail
    0x33, // packet tail
    0xc3, // packet tail
    0x3c // packet tail
  };


void writeDisplay(const char* text)
{
  // Write packet headers
  DISPLAY_DEVICE.write(displayPktStart, sizeof displayPktStart);

  // Send text
  DISPLAY_DEVICE.print(text);

  // Write packet tail
  DISPLAY_DEVICE.write(displayPktEnd, sizeof displayPktEnd); 
}

void writeDisplay(const String& text)
{
  writeDisplay(text.c_str());
}

void setup()
{
  DISPLAY_DEVICE.begin(DISPLAY_DEVICE_BAUD);
}

void loop() 
{
  String msg = "TOPWAY";
  writeDisplay(msg);

  delay(2000);
  writeDisplay("Peanuts taste like chicken");
  delay(500);
  writeDisplay("");
  delay(1000);
  writeDisplay("No. Seriously");
  delay(2000);
}
```

Comment: 1. Instead of writing a loop, you can `DISPLAY_DEVICE.write(displayPktStart, sizeof displayPktStart);`, and likewise for `displayPktEnd`. 2. You mean `DISPLAY_DEVICE.print(text);`, not `println()`. 3. `Serial.print()` will not send the terminating `\0`, you may want to add that to `displayPktEnd`.

Comment: @EdgarBonet Thanks. Updated.

Comment: Thanks A lot. I've added DISPLAY_DEVICE.begin(9600); in setup

Comment: @mehmet I hope my update matches your expectations.

Comment: @voidPointer well, I don't want to bother you too much, but I have one more question. if I want to use dynamic address, such as "000080" instead of     Serial.write(0x00);
    Serial.write(0x00);    
    Serial.write(0x80); how to add this method, like writeDisplay(msg, "000080");

Comment: @mehmet Remove the address from displayPktStart, add uint32_t parameter to both writeDisplay and send it after directly after DISPLAY_DEVICE.write(displayPktStart,...